# Changing the StartPoint/EndPoint of a LinearGradient brush in Expression Blend UI

Tags: xaml, expression-blend, lineargradientbrush

Seems like as really simple thing to do, but I just can't track it down in the help or online.

I know how to change the XAML to set the StartPoint and EndPoint of a LinearGradient brush, but I don't know how you do it using the IDE in Expression Blend - does anyone know the keyboard/mouse actions that you use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the object that you want to modify in the art pane
2. Select the Brush you want to modify in the Brushes properties group
3. Select the Brush Transform tool (it's the arrow that is the 7th from the top) on the left.
4. Drag the arrow head and arrow tail to modify the startpoint and endpoint.